# Always getting error "after end Result set" and all result set already close

Tags: java, mysql

I want to make a Java application that, when I click button, it can open Google Maps in browser. Location, latitude, and longitude I can take from a MySQL database. But if I am running that class, "After end of result" always appears even though all results set already close. This is my code:

```
while(rs.next()) {
                String getKodeLokasi = rs.getString("kode_lokasi");
                if ((kode_lokasi.equals(getKodeLokasi))){
                    check = true;
                }
                break;
            }

if (check) {
    String latitude = "SELECT latitude FROM data_lokasi WHERE kode_lokasi = '"+kode_lokasi+"'";
    String getLat = rs.getString("latitude");    <<<<----- After end of result set

    String longtitude = "SELECT longtitude FROM data_lokasi WHERE kode_lokasi = '"+kode_lokasi+"'";
    String getLong = rs.getString("longtitude");

    String lokasi = "SELECT lokasi FROM data_lokasi WHERE kode_lokasi = '"+kode_lokasi+"'";
    String getLokasi = (rs.getString("lokasi")).replace(" ", "+");

    if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){    
         Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/'"+getLokasi+"'/@'"+getLat+"','"+getLong+"',17z/"));
    }                          
} else {              
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Can't find code!");
}
```

Whats wrong with my code? Thanks before and please help me :')

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but you seem to be saying that you invoke the `getString()` method of a `ResultSet` that has already been closed.  If that's the case, then that's the problem.  You must not continue to use a `ResultSet` after you close it (including if you close the `Statement` the produced it or the `Connection` to which that `Statement` belongs, which also closes the `ResultSet`).

Comment: Also, the actual question has nothing to do with Google maps.  Tag removed.

Comment: i.m sorry i.m forgot about previous code. I already edit it

Comment: after the while loop your are at the end of the resultset, call begoreFirst to rewind. if you have create your stztement with bzckward capabilities

Comment: Did you mean `rs.beforeFirst();` @Tokazio?

Comment: if yes, where I must put it to my code? @Tokazio?

Comment: sorry i've read your code too fast. break the while loop after the first iteration is same as just call rs.next() i think your break statement should be in the if statement.

Comment: so I must to put `break;` on the if statement right @Tokazio ?

Comment: don't know, don't understand what you try to achieve... show query please

Comment: my bad.. I was wrong when putting `break;` by the way thanks a lot @Tokazio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scroll all the way to the end of your `ResultSet`.  At that point, it is no longer on a valid row, so there are no column values to read.  In particular, you cannot read any values from the row for which `kode_lokasi.equals(getKodeLokasi)` evaluated to `true`.

If you expect no more than one row, then change the `while` loop into an `if` block, so that `rs.next()` is invoked only once.  If you need to accommodate multiple result rows, then you probably need to `break` out of the loop when you find the one you're looking for, so that `rs.next()` is not invoked on the `ResultSet` again.

The theme here is that if you want to read values from the result row that satisfies your condition, then after finding that row you must not move on to another.

Comment: Also, I see no reason why you *should* need to be concerned with more than one row, nor why you would need to check a simple equality condition on one of the result columns.  If you want to filter rows then put that in your query instead of post-processing the results.  Making the DB handle the filtering is both cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: I am filter each row and put it on the link because I didn't know source code how filter rows then put that in my query instead of post-processing the results efficiently. Maybe this is the way I know to filter it @John Bollinger

Comment: I already add `break;` on my loop but my java app just identify first data. My app can't identifying second, third etc :( @John Bollinger

Comment: @Dompet, you filter rows in your query by adding a `WHERE` condition to it.

Comment: @Dompet, you (seem to) want to `break` *only* in the case that your `if` condition is satisfied -- that is, under the same circumstance that you set `check` to true -- but in your current code you break unconditionally at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: ahhh my bad... yeah you're right @John Bollinger. This work in my app. Thanks a lot :)